# shooting multiple bullets from the same class

Tags: java, android, swing

the following code snippet I created has a rectangle shooting a bullet . I want the bullet class to be called everytime there is a new bullet "summoned" by the space bar and has it independent of the last bullet. what would be the first steps to creating multiple instances of bullet on the screen at once?

drawingComponent class :

```
package scratch;


import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.Timer;




import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.util.*;

public class drawingComponent extends JComponent implements KeyListener {
    private Timer timer;
    public int count = 0;
    public Rectangle hello = new Rectangle(100, 300, 50, 50);
    Integer x1 = hello.x;
    Integer y1 = hello.y;
    public Bullet bullet = new Bullet(hello.x, hello.y);

    boolean fired = false;




    public drawingComponent() {
        addKeyListener(this);



    }


    public class TimerListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            count++;



            bullet.fired();
            repaint();

            System.out.println(count + "seconds.");
        }

    }


    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (fired == true) {

            bullet.drawBullet(g);
        }
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        g2.setColor(new Color(255, 25, 0));
        g2.setFont(new Font("monospace", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 30));
        g2.drawString("nothing yet", 300, 320);
        g2.fill(hello);



        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();

    }






    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {

            hello.y = hello.y - 1;
            hello.setLocation(hello.x, hello.y);

            repaint();
            System.out.println(hello.y);
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            hello.y = hello.y + 1;
            hello.setLocation(hello.x, hello.y);
            repaint();

        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            hello.x = hello.x - 1;
            hello.setLocation(hello.x, hello.y);
            repaint();

        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            hello.x = hello.x + 1;
            hello.setLocation(hello.x, hello.y);
            repaint();

        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {

            bullet.update(hello.x, hello.y);
            fired = true;
            if (count > 5) {
                timer.stop();
            }
            timer = new Timer(50, new TimerListener());
            timer.start();


            repaint();

        }





    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {


            //  fired = false;



            repaint();

        }


    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

bullet class :

```
package scratch;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class Bullet {
    Rectangle BulletRect = new Rectangle(20, 20, 20, 20);

    public Bullet(int x, int y2) {

        BulletRect.y = y2;
        BulletRect.x = x;


    }
    public void fired() {

        BulletRect.y = BulletRect.y + 50;


    }

    public void update(int x1, int y4) {

        BulletRect.x = x1;
        BulletRect.y = y4;
    }

    public void drawBullet(Graphics g) {


        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;


        g2.fill(BulletRect);
    }
    // get bullets position

    //increment bullets position every so often

    //when bullet goes off screen, clear it from game





}
```

also, if I may could pose another question , what route would best to go down if I wanted to start learning android from swing? thanks.

Comment: Create a List, which will maintain a List of the currently active bullets, use this to update and paint the bullets, when ever space is pressed, add a new button to the list. You might also want to consider using the key bindings api over using KeyListener

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few pointers for you (I am assuming you are using Java 8).

- Instead of `public Bullet bullet = new Bullet(hello.x, hello.y);` use `private List<Bullet> bullets = new ArrayList<>();`
- When you create a new bullet (when you detect spacebar) add it to the list: `bullets.add(new Bullet(x, y));`
- When you need to draw all the bullets in `paintComponent` you can use `bullets.stream().forEach(bullet -> bullet.drawBullet(g));`
- There's no need for the `fired` field any longer: an empty bullets list is the same as not fired.
- Each tick you'll need to remove bullets that aren't on the screen. This can be done with something like: `bullets.removeIf(Bullet::isOffScreen);` assuming you implement an isOffScreen method.